# NLog ConfigSettingLayoutRenderer - the best place to set configuration

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, nlog

I would like to store some parts of the Nlog configurations (like DB connection string) at appsettings.json (production data are coming from the azure key vault)
To do that I have to put something like that:

```
NLog.Extensions.Logging.ConfigSettingLayoutRenderer.DefaultConfiguration = configuration;
```

Assuming that I'm using the Blazor Server side app, where is the best place to put that line?

Answer (score 1):

The entry point sounds like a good idea, so Program.cs for Blazor Server apps.

> Program.cs is the entry point for the app that starts the server and where you configure the app services and middleware

From [Blazor Server Tutorial](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/aspnet/blazor-tutorial/create)